# How to put apt and python packages in a list and check if installed or not then install

Tags: performance, bash, shell

I am not an expert in shell scripting,

I need help optimizing the shell script I wrote, This shell script I wrote is run by users on the client side who connect to our vpn server from the setting passed in the config.tar.

I check if pip or or tar or other packaches are installed if not isntalled than install it, I am doing it in separate if condition, what I want to achieve is I put the packages to check in a  listand then iterate if not installed than install it for all apt, pip or pip3 packages.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                
set -

command=`which pip`

if [ "$command" = "" ]
then
    echo "The pip program not exist on this system."
    sudo apt-get install python-pip -y
    sudo apt install python3-pip -y
else
    echo "Pip is intalled."
fi
sudo apt install speedtest-cli
pip install -U pip
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
pip3 install pymysql
pip3 install sqlalchemy

TAR=`which tar`

if [ "$TAR" = "" ]
then
    echo "Tar is not installed,  installing now."
    sudo apt-get install tar -y
else
    echo "Tar is installed."
fi

# lets install requests 
pip install requests

cd $HOME
echo "Iniating download..."
curl -sL "http://my.domain.com/config" -o "config.tar"

tar xvf config.tar
sudo chmod 604 ucc.py 

if [ -e ucc.py ]
then
    echo "ucc.py installed."
else
    echo "ucc.py failed to download."
fi

if [ -e ucc.service ]
then
    echo "ucc.service installed."
else
    echo "ucc.service failed to download."
fi

sudo mv ucc.service "/lib/systemd/system/"

if [ -e client.conf ]
then
    sudo mv client.conf /etc/openvpn/
    echo "client.conf downloaded."
else
    echo "client.conf failed to download."
fi

sudo mv -f client.conf /etc/openvpn/

cd /etc/openvpn/

if [ -e client.conf ]
then
    echo "client.conf installed."
else
    echo "client.conf failed to download."
fi

sudo systemctl restart openvpn@client
sudo systemctl status  openvpn@client
```

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the apt-get install, why not just run the install command? Nothing bad should happen from attempting to install a package that already exists

Comment: thats because on client side end user is non-technical person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use for loops for expandability and readability.
2. If you want to test for individual utilities, try using `command -v pip` instead of which and comparing against that.
3. Look up and understand the functional difference between single bracket comparisons and double bracket. [ ] vs [[ ]]
4. `` syntax is very out of date, use $()
5. If you have to call /usr/bin/env for the location of bash, but broadly assume apt is the package manager on the system, it's much safer to use /bin/bash.
6. Python requests is also stored as an apt package, I moved it into the first for loop statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

for PACKAGE in python-pip python-pip3 speedtest-cli tar python-requests; do
    if [[ ! $(dpkg -l ${PACKAGE}) ]] ; then
        echo "${PACKAGE} is not installed, installing now."
        sudo apt-get install ${PACKAGE} -y
    else
        echo "${PACKAGE} is installed."
    fi
done

pip3 install -U pip

for PACKAGE in mysql-connector-python pymysql sqlalchemy ; do
    pip3 install -U ${PACKAGE}

    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then echo "${PACKAGE} failed to installed" ; fi
done

cd $HOME
echo "Iniating download..."
curl -sL "http://my.domain.com/config" -o "config.tar"

tar xvf config.tar

sudo chmod 604 ucc.py
## I don't know why you need to use sudo to chmod an item inside your own home dir, but ill leave this here.
## Also, you can tar a package with certian perms and then unpack it to obey those specific permissions.

for ITEM in ucc.py ucc.service client.conf; do
    if [[ -e ${ITEM} ]] ; then
         echo "${ITEM} is installed."
    else
        echo "${ITEM} failed to download"
    fi
done

sudo mv ucc.service /lib/systemd/system/
sudo mv client.conf /etc/openvpn/
sudo mv -f client.conf /etc/openvpn/

sudo systemctl restart openvpn@client
sudo systemctl status  openvpn@client
```

Comment: do you mean if i set the file permission and tar it on extraction those permission attributes will be preserved?

Comment: @ChangZhao https://askubuntu.com/questions/463325/what-does-tars-p-preserve-permissions-flag-actually-preserve